# Replace values in column based on same or closer values from another columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes look like:

DF1:

| Score 1 | Avg_life |
| --- | --- |
| 4.033986 | 3482.0 |
| 9.103820 | 758.0 |
| -1.34432 | 68000.0 |
| 218670040.0 | 33708.0 |
| 2.291000 | 432.0 |

DF2:

| Score 1 | life |
| --- | --- |
| 3.033986 | 0 |
| 9.103820 | 0 |
| 9.103820 | 0 |
| 7.350981 | 0 |
| 1.443400 | 0 |
| 9.103820 | 0 |
| -1.134486 | 0 |

The 0 values in "life" from second dataframe should be replaced by the values from "avg life" from the first dataframe if the columns "Score 1" from both dataframes are the same. Btw if there are no the same values, we take the closest value from "Score1" in DF1 to value from "Score1" in DF2.

The problem is in the word "the closest".

For example:
I don't have the value "3.033986" in DF1 in "Score 1", but I want to take the closest value to this - "4.033986" and change 0 in "life" column to "3482.0" from "Avg_life" because "3.033986" is closer to "4.033986".

The result should be like this:

DF_result:

| Score 1 | life |
| --- | --- |
| 3.033986 | 3482.0 |
| 9.103820 | 758.0 |
| 9.103820 | 758.0 |
| 7.350981 | 758.0 |
| 1.443400 | 432.0 |
| 9.103820 | 758.0 |
| -1.134486 | 68000.0 |

I hope I made it clear....

Thanks for all help!

Comment: When you say "close" is there a certain `threshold` value you want (like 3.033986 from DF2 is within `1.00` of 4.033986 in DF1) or do you mean the "closest" value to 3.033986 that is in DF1 ?

Comment: @DerekO oh sorry for an inaccuracy, I mean the closest value to 3.033986 that is in DF1 if there isn't the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we find the value if `df1['Score1']` that is the closest to each value in `df2['Score1']`, and put it into `df2['match']`:

```
df2['match'] = df2['Score1'].apply(lambda s : min(df1['Score1'].values, key = lambda x: abs(x-s)))
```

`df2` now looks like this

```
    Score1   life   match
0   3.033986    0   2.29100
1   9.103820    0   9.10382
2   9.103820    0   9.10382
3   7.350981    0   9.10382
4   1.443400    0   2.29100
5   9.103820    0   9.10382
6   -1.134486   0   -1.34432
```

Now we just merge on `match`, drop unneeded columns and rename others

```
(df2[['match', 'Score1']].merge(df1, how = 'left', left_on = 'match', right_on = 'Score1', suffixes = ['','_2'])
    .rename(columns = {'Avg_life':'life'})
    .drop(columns = ['match', 'Score1_2'])
)
```

output

```
    Score1      life
0   3.033986    432.0
1   9.103820    758.0
2   9.103820    758.0
3   7.350981    758.0
4   1.443400    432.0
5   9.103820    758.0
6   -1.134486   68000.0
```

Answer (score 3):

If order in the result set doesn't matter, we can sort both DataFrames with [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) then [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to get the `nearest` match.

`"nearest"` search:

> selects the row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is closest in absolute distance to the left’s key.

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(
    df2.sort_values('Score 1'),
    df1.sort_values('Score 1'),
    on='Score 1',
    direction='nearest'
)

    Score 1  life  Avg_life
0 -1.134486     0   68000.0
1  1.443400     0     432.0
2  3.033986     0     432.0
3  7.350981     0     758.0
4  9.103820     0     758.0
5  9.103820     0     758.0
6  9.103820     0     758.0
```

[drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) can be used to clean up the output:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(
    df2.sort_values('Score 1'),
    df1.sort_values('Score 1'),
    on='Score 1',
    direction='nearest'
).drop(columns='life').rename(columns={'Avg_life': 'life'})

    Score 1     life
0 -1.134486  68000.0
1  1.443400    432.0
2  3.033986    432.0
3  7.350981    758.0
4  9.103820    758.0
5  9.103820    758.0
6  9.103820    758.0
```

---

If order is important, we can sort df2 outside of [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and overwrite the result set with the index of `df2` with [set_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) then [sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to restore the initial order:

```
df2_sorted = df2.sort_values('Score 1')
df3 = (
    pd.merge_asof(df2_sorted,
                  df1.sort_values('Score 1'),
                  on='Score 1',
                  direction='nearest')
        .drop(columns='life')
        .rename(columns={'Avg_life': 'life'})
        .set_axis(df2_sorted.index, axis=0)
        .sort_index()
)

    Score 1     life
0  3.033986    432.0
1  9.103820    758.0
2  9.103820    758.0
3  7.350981    758.0
4  1.443400    432.0
5  9.103820    758.0
6 -1.134486  68000.0
```